# How can I export Stata files into CSV while keeping double format?

Tags: export, double, stata

I am exporting variables from Stata into csv file, but the variables using "double" format/storage only shows 0's while in fact they should be decimal numbers. Is there a way to save these "double" or "float" variables into CSV as decimals?

I am new in Stata so any help is appreciated

Comment: If you're looking at the data in a spreadsheet, this appearance can be a delusion. To check on what is in a .csv, just type it or look at it in a text editor.